# Relation Between Poisson and Bernoulli Distribution.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are observations of iid Poisson$(\lambda)$ random variables. Suppose that the Bernoulli random variable $Y$ is derived from $X$ by

$$ Y =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $X=0$} \\
0, & \text{if $X>0$}.
\end{cases}$$

Does it mean $\mathbb P(Y_i=1)=\mathbb P(X_i=0)=\frac{\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^0}{0!}=\exp(-\lambda)?$

That is, exponent of negative value of rate parameter of a Poisson distribution is the probability of success of a Bernoulli distribution???

Comment: Yes, and $\sum Y_i$ is a binomial random with parameters $n$ and $\exp(-\lambda)$

Comment: @Henry Thank you.